# xcode, align 20 images, grid view

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Need some help ^_^,

I'm trying to align 20 images together, in the storyboard,

https://www.dropbox.com/s/cnyojn82rn84c9j/pic1.jpg?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/05u50dd54w756q7/pic2.jpg?dl=0

I need them to look same in the portrait and landscape mode, so if you imagine rotating phone, then 20 pictures rotate 90 degrees, but not the whole view, when view rotates to landscape, bottom row disappears.

Sorry, it's hard to explain =D, basically in portrait top row has 4 pictures, in landscape top row **should** have 5 pictures.

Would be even better if they would change size of the image depending on the screen size.

Thanks,

Comment: You should use autolayout or autoresizing for this. 

http://www.raywenderlich.com/83129/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-swift-part-1

http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Why there is need of 20 images to be designed in storyboard, When we have [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionView_class/) for that purpose, you never need to worry about the rotation, Collection view will automatically adjust it cells accordingly.*

If you need tutorial you can surely go ahead with this [link](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you look into UICollection views with a flow layout. It might sound unwieldy at first but it is definitely the best solution for what you want to achieve. Apple documentation can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CollectionViewPGforIOS.pdf